# How to select record from Snowflake stage file path including today's date in it

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have file on date and hour path location yyyy/mm/dd/hh.
Now i wants to fetch file for today date eg.2023/03/27/04

I wants to select all records from file on date location.

my code is below:

```
set date_hour_folder=TO_VARCHAR(DATEADD(hour, -6, convert_timezone('UTC', current_timestamp())), 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh');


SELECT
$1:name ,
$1:address ,
$1:id 

FROM  @test_prod.test/dev/test/device_d_rollup_parquet_expor2t/{date_hour_folder}/  (file_format => 'my_parquet_format', PATTERN => '.*.parquet')
```

Note : **date_hour_folder** is the date in **yyyy/mm/dd/hh** format.

Above mentioned code is not working, My Query is how can we pass dynamic **date_hour_folder** variable to select data from stage file(dynamic date folder location).
Or any other way to do this select operation.

Comment: This is not working directly, unless you wrap the SQL statement into a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Sergiu Can you please help me with sample queries, or any suitable link for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working directly, unless you wrap the SQL statement into a Stored Procedure.

As for a simple example using Javascript (you can write Stored Procedures in SQL, Javascript, Python, Java, Scala):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_date_hour(d1 varchar(30))
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$
 var cmd = `SELECT $1, $2, $3 FROM  @~/` + D1 + `/1651011730.067872/filename_0_0_0.csv.gz  (file_format => 'CSV_DEMO', pattern=>'.*[.]csv.gz');`
 var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: cmd});
 var result1 = stmt.execute();
 while (result1.next()) {
  var column1 = result1.getColumnValue(1);
  var column2 = result1.getColumnValue(2);
  var column3 = result1.getColumnValue(3);
 }
 return column1 + ' ' + column2 + ' ' + column3
$$
;
```

I call the stored procedure:

```
call test_date_hour('2022-06-09');
```

and I get back the first row:

```
"5AC01667E8C72C5D" "docked_bike" "2021-04-30 05:47:16.000"
```

More on Snowflake's Stored Procedures [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview).